# Processing a list to return true/false values using a for loop - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have written this function trying to get it to return true or false in terms of the following condition, however I get this result when testing it:

`>>> has_gt([2,3,4], 2)
False`

```
def has_gt(nums, n):
"""Return True iff nums contains at least one number bigger than n.

has_gt(list<number>, number) -> boolean
"""
for i in (nums, n):
    if i in nums > n:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def has_gt(myList, value):
    return any(i > value for i in myList)

>>> has_gt([2,3,4], 3)
True
>>> has_gt([1,2,3], 7)
False
```

Using a for loop

```
def has_gt(myList, value):
    for i in myList:
        if i > value:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: I would like to use a for loop though